# How to include sub tasks in Greenhopper burndown chart calculation?

Tags: jira, jira-agile, burndowncharts

We are currently using the burndown chart in Greenhopper in "Issue Count" mode. At the moment only the standard issue types (bugs, tasks, stories) are considered in calculating the burndown.

**Question:** Is there an option to consider also sub-tasks in the burndown calculation?

***Example:**
Let's assume we have 3 stories and 8 sub-tasks related to them. If I close a story, the burndown chart is affected. But if I close a sub-task, the chart is not affected.*

I have checked the project filter, that includes also the sub tasks. But for some reason they are not considered in the graphs (which is bad, for us).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's not supported, as you can see in the issue [Original time estimate on the rapidboard is not sum by sub-task](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-5653) :

> We do not plan on modifying this behaviour because the main purpose of the original estimate is to calculate velocity. Using sub task estimates corrupts the velocity as discussed in [this answers post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/84349/rapid-board-time-estimates-with-sub-tasks?page=1#84605).
>
> In GreenHopper 6.0.3 we've enabled the remaining estimate to be shown as a rollup on the sprint footer. Please check out the [release notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/GreenHopper+6.0.3+Release+Notes#GreenHopper6.0.3ReleaseNotes-EasiermanagementofRemainingEstimate) for more information.